# How can I find the Solution properties in water like "Solubility"?

Tags: data, chemistry

[The official documentation of function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChemicalData.html) `ChemicalData` says it can find solution properties in water below:

[image]

But I have made several attempts, none of them have succeeded:

```
ChemicalData["SodiumChloride", "Solubility"]
```

gives:

> Missing["NotAvailable"]

```
ChemicalData["CarbonDioxide", "HenryLawConstant"]
```

gives:

> Missing["NotAvailable"]

Anybody knows how to find those solution properties properly? It is weird that those properties are listed in documentation but cannot be found straightforwardly.

By the way, my PC is a Win 10 with MMA version of 12.3.

Comment: It looks like data simply is not present in their curated database. It is also not available in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=NaCl+solubility). Perhaps contacting the Wolfram Research ChemicalData team (datasources@wolfram.com) is what you should do, as written [on the ``ChemicalData`` page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/note/ChemicalDataSourceInformation.html).

Comment: Thanks @Domen, I will try to contact them as soon as possible.